# How do I redirect the user to another HTML page using my button after checking for email input validation?

Tags: javascript, css, html, frontend

**Full Question:** How do I redirect the user to another HTML page using my button after the program checks if the email input entered by the user is valid using the automatic email input validation built into the browser? I'm assuming I would have to use an if/else statement in JavaScript?

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Testing Web Page!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Stay up to date with ecommerce trends <br>with Shopify's newsletter</h2>
  <h4>Subscribe for free marketing tips</h4>

  <script>
    function logOptions() {
      var s = document.getElementsByName('Interests')[0];
      var text = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
      console.log(text);
    }

    function logEmail() {
      console.log(document.getElementById('emailinput').value);
    }

    /*  function checkEmail(){
        if(!document.getElementById("emailinput").checkValidity()){
          alert("input not valid!");
        }
      }
    */

    function myFunction() {
      logOptions();
      logEmail();
    }
  </script>


  <!-- <div class="input form"> -->
  <form id="inputform">
    <input id="emailinput" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <span id='errorMessage'></span>
    <select name="Interests">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Interested in..</option>
        <option value="option1">Marketing</option>
        <option value="option2">Option2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option4</option>
      </select>
  </form>


  <!-- Sign up now button -->
  <div id="container">
    <button id="submitButton" form="inputform" onclick="myFunction()">Sign up now</button>
  </div>

  <svg>
  <rect width="40" height="3" style="fill:lightgreen" />
  </svg>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("inputform").submit();

Comment: where do I put this @Charles Shiller?

Comment: You need anything more? @syed

Answer (score 0):

not sure where this "automatic email input validation" that you mention,so i just put the redirection script inside myFunction.

if you try it, it will redirect to stackoverflow when you click the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Testing Web Page!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Stay up to date with ecommerce trends <br>with Shopify's newsletter</h2>
  <h4>Subscribe for free marketing tips</h4>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function logOptions() {
      var s = document.getElementsByName('Interests')[0];
      var text = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
    }

    function logEmail() {
      console.log(document.getElementById('emailinput').value);

    }

    /*  function checkEmail(){
        if(!document.getElementById("emailinput").checkValidity()){
          alert("input not valid!");
        }
      }
    */

    function myFunction() {
      logOptions();
      logEmail();
      window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
      return false;
    }
  </script>


  <!-- <div class="input form"> -->
  <form id="inputform">
    <input id="emailinput" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <span id='errorMessage'></span>
    <select name="Interests">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Interested in..</option>
        <option value="option1">Marketing</option>
        <option value="option2">Option2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option4</option>
      </select>
  </form>


  <!-- Sign up now button -->
  <div id="container">
    <button id="submitButton" form="inputform" onclick="return myFunction();">Sign up now</button>
  </div>

  <svg>
  <rect width="40" height="3" style="fill:lightgreen" />
  </svg>


</body>



</html>
```

later if you already have the validation method, you can just use something like this

```
if(valid)
   window.location.href="url to valid email page";
else
   window.location.href="url to error page";
```

Answer (score 0):

onkeyup event always check your input. and validate email regex check your input. I think it solved your requirement.

```js
function logOptions() {
      var s = document.getElementsByName('Interests')[0];
      var text = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
      console.log(text);
    }

    function logEmail() {
      console.log(document.getElementById('emailinput').value);
    }
    
    function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }

    function checkEmail(){
  var str = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
  document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = validateEmail(str);
    }

    function myFunction() {
      var str = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
      if(validateEmail(str)){
        logOptions();
        logEmail();
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Testing Web Page!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Stay up to date with ecommerce trends <br>with Shopify's newsletter</h2>
  <h4>Subscribe for free marketing tips</h4>

  <!-- <div class="input form"> -->
  <form id="inputform">
    <input id="emailinput" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" onkeyup="checkEmail()">
    <span id='errorMessage'></span>
    <select name="Interests">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Interested in..</option>
        <option value="option1">Marketing</option>
        <option value="option2">Option2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option4</option>
      </select>
  </form>
<br><br>

  <!-- Sign up now button -->
  <div id="container">
    <button id="submitButton" form="inputform" onclick="myFunction()">Sign up now</button>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```